# Trigger to increment an ID by 1 on insert in visual studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have been struggling to getting an incremental trigger working in visual studios local database.

I have an Admin_ID primary key in the Admin table. I am wanting to get a trigger sorted so each time i add a row in the table. The trigger will create its own ID according to previous ID's before it.

Here is the layout for it. Any ideas on how to do it?

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Trigger]
    ON [dbo].[ ]
    FOR INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON
    END
```

Comment: Why not use the auto-inc mechanism built into the DB?

Comment: @juergend i am unaware of this, could you explain please?

Comment: You tagged MySQL but it looks like MSSQL syntax. Just look up *auto-increment* and in MSSQL it is called IDENTITY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use identity values LIKE

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test (
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
COLUMN1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.test (COLUMN1) VALUES ('test');
INSERT INTO dbo.test (COLUMN1) VALUES ('test');
```

This will insert:

```
ID | COLUMN1
1  | test
2  | test
```